How to restore a mongodump that's one single file
A few months ago I did a dump of my mongodump db and it resulted in a single file instead of multiple bson and json files:

I tried to restore it using:

mongorestore --drop --db lodeep dump

dump is the folder containing the file but I get this:

I don't remember how exactly I made this dump. And why it's not like the usual dump. And why the file has no extension. I'm a bit lost. I really need this data.
When I do this:

head mongodump-prod-db

I see that it's indeed my database and its collections:

Any help please?

I remembered now I used this command to dump it:

mongodump --uri
'mongodb+srv://XXXX:XXXXXXXXX@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/DB_NAME'
--archive="mongodump-prod-db" --forceTableScan

And if I want to restore it to the cloud, I do this:

mongorestore --uri
'mongodb+srv://XXXX:XXXXXXXXX@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/DB_NAME'
--archive="mongodump-prod-db" --nsFrom='DB_NAME.' --nsTo='copy_new_db.'

I tried to restore it locally:

mongorestore --uri 'mongodb://localhost:27017/<local_dbname>'
--archive="mongodump-prod-db"

But it results in this:


I also tried to restore it to the cloud:

mongorestore --uri
'mongodb+srv://XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@cluster0.mchmj.mongodb.net/myDatabase'
--archive="mongodump-prod-db" --nsFrom='myDatabase.originalCollection' --nsTo='myDatabase.copy_new_collection'

And I see this:


I tried this:

mongorestore --archive="mongodump-prod-db" --db restoreddb --verbose

It shows it's reading collections names but then it restores nothing:
2024-10-06T16:05:45.499+0200    using write concern: &{majority <nil> 0s}
2024-10-06T16:05:45.524+0200    The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
2024-10-06T16:05:45.551+0200    archive prelude <dbname>.users
2024-10-06T16:05:45.560+0200    archive prelude <dbname>.badges
2024-10-06T16:05:45.631+0200    preparing collections to restore from
2024-10-06T16:06:16.228+0200    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.


Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Try simple mongorestore --uri 'mongodb://localhost:27017' --archive="mongodump-prod-db". Maybe even mongorestore --archive="mongodump-prod-db will work, because localhost:27017 is the default

Okay this is a bit stupid. But the database name of the dump is literally  < dbname > (minus the spaces) so when I run this command:

mongorestore --archive="mongodump-prod-db" --verbose
--nsInclude=.*

mongorestore ignore <> and interprets it as dbname. And so it doesn't find the database in the dump.
So I had to do this:
mongorestore --archive="mongodump-prod-db" --verbose \
--nsFrom="<dbname>.*" --nsTo="newdbname.*"

And it worked!

You can restore a single file dump with the command
mongorestore --drop < dump

The database name will be taken from the file. If you used the --archive flag when doing the dump, you have to add the option to the restore command.

It's not a .gz file. It seems to have no extension

Correct, if the dump is gzipped, you have to add --gzip flag also
